# Bit shift portability

Tags: c++, bit-manipulation, portability

My question is rather direct, is this code portable?

```
#include  <cstdint>

#ifndef  ECS_INT
  #define  ECS_INT  uint32_t
#endif

#ifndef  ECS_MAX_NB_COMPONENTS
  #define  ECS_MAX_NB_COMPONENTS  255
#endif

static constexpr uint8_t  FIND_MAX_NUMBER_OF_BITS(uint64_t base) {

  //! Round to upper pow2
  base--;
  base |= base >> 1;
  base |= base >> 2;
  base |= base >> 4;
  base |= base >> 8;
  base |= base >> 16;
  base |= base >> 32;
  base++;

  //! Check bits number
  uint8_t  counter = 0;
  while (!(base & (1 << counter)))
    ++counter;
  return counter;
}

static constexpr const ECS_INT  INVALID_INDEX           = ((ECS_INT) - 1);
static constexpr const uint8_t  ECS_INT_MAX_BITS        = FIND_MAX_NUMBER_OF_BITS(INVALID_INDEX) + 1;
static constexpr const uint8_t  ECS_COMPONENT_MAX_BITS  = FIND_MAX_NUMBER_OF_BITS(ECS_MAX_NB_COMPONENTS);
```

I'm not an expert about bits but I think the language allow this to be portable. Or maybe I should use something like `std::bitset` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- `1 << counter` should be `(uint64_t)1 << counter` otherwise it is undefined behaviour when `counter` reaches `sizeof(int) * CHAR_BIT` (and implementation-defined when one less than that).
- Even after fixing that, the loop will evaluate `(uint64_t)1 << 64` for some inputs, which is undefined behaviour, so you need to add pre-checks or a loop condition to prevent that.

Comment: (uint64_t)1 << 64 is the case with max value no? So I can't know if I need 64bits for this case? 63bits max then? Do you know a better way to check to do this?

Comment: you could break the loop if `counter == 64`, or something

Comment: oh you're right that's just an algo error. I was afraid for nothing sorry. Anyways thanks :)